# OpenSSL ECC key - Additional byte in DER encoding for one curve

Tags: openssl, ecc, asn1

In the below, I use OpenSSL to create a private key for the secp224k1 curve. Note the length of the private key in the DER - 0x1d. That's 29 bytes, or 232 bits, not 224. It appears that a leading zero byte has been prepended.

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018

$ openssl ecparam -name secp224k1 -genkey -noout -outform DER -out ~/secp224k1.der 

$ certutil -asn ~/secp224k1.der
0000: 30 69                                     ; SEQUENCE (69 Bytes)
0002:    02 01                                  ; INTEGER (1 Bytes)
0004:    |  01
0005:    04 1d                                  ; OCTET_STRING (1d Bytes)
0007:    |  00 9b 69 d2 25 22 85 cc  58 c5 57 29 7e 59 02 6f  ; ..i.%"..X.W)~Y.o
0017:    |  ee 90 b1 f7 7e 78 c3 10  5c 20 52 22 78           ; ....~x..\ R"x
0024:    a0 07                                  ; OPTIONAL[0] (7 Bytes)
0026:    |  06 05                               ; OBJECT_ID (5 Bytes)
0028:    |     2b 81 04 00 20
         |        ; 1.3.132.0.32 secP224k1
002d:    a1 3c                                  ; OPTIONAL[1] (3c Bytes)
002f:       03 3a 00 04 47 21 06 a1  dc ea 7d 12 e9 0f 00 29  ; .:..G!....}....)
003f:       ca 5d db 67 3f 51 e3 b3  a7 5a b6 8c d3 23 f6 93  ; .].g?Q...Z...#..
004f:       7f 8a a2 fe ce cb d9 22  f1 92 95 69 4f 25 08 3a  ; ......."...iO%.:
005f:       0d 28 1a 27 a8 99 0e 5f  0b e0 17 b5              ; .(.'..._....
```

Now, since this is OCTET_STRING, not INTEGER, the number having MSB 1 should not have led automatically to the prepended zero byte. Indeed, for secp224r1, it does not:

```
0005:    04 1c                                  ; OCTET_STRING (1c Bytes)
0007:    |  e5 5f 38 18 d8 7b ca 84  85 f3 c0 1a c7 83 21 bf  ; ._8..{........!.
0017:    |  b9 f9 ed 9c 83 2b b5 b0  ce 15 6c 0b              ; .....+....l.
```

This behaviour does not occur for either of the secp256r1 and secp256k1 curves. Does any one know why it would have happened for this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although for secp224k1 the size of the underlying field, and thus point coordinates including a public key, is (slightly) smaller than 2<sup>224</sup>, **the order of the curve group**, and thus the size of a *private* key, is slightly larger than 2<sup>224</sup> and **nominally requires 29 octets to represent** -- even though the probability of d chosen uniformly at random per spec actually needing 29 octets is so small it probably won't happen during the Earth's lifetime. Quoting SEC2 from http://www.secg.org (since it's free and X9.62 isn't) minus formatting I can't reproduce without MathJax:

> 2.3.1 Recommended Parameters secp224k1
>   The elliptic curve domain parameters over **F**<sub>p</sub> associated with a Koblitz curve secp224k1 are
>   specified by the sextuple T = (p, a, b, G, n, h) where the finite field **F**<sub>p</sub> is defined by:
>   p = FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE FFFFE56D
>   = 2<sup>224</sup> − 2<sup>32</sup> − 2<sup>12</sup> − 2<sup>11</sup> − 2<sup>9</sup> − 2<sup>7</sup> − 2<sup>4</sup> − 2 − 1
>   The curve E: y<sup>2</sup> = x<sup>3</sup> + ax + b over **F**<sub>p</sub> is defined by:
>   a = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   b = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000005
>   The base point G in compressed form is:
>   G = 03 A1455B33 4DF099DF 30FC28A1 69A467E9 E47075A9 0F7E650E
>   B6B7A45C
>   and in uncompressed form is:
>   G = 04 A1455B33 4DF099DF 30FC28A1 69A467E9 E47075A9 0F7E650E 
>   B6B7A45C 7E089FED 7FBA3442 82CAFBD6 F7E319F7 C0B0BD59 E2CA4BDB
>   556D61A5
>   Finally the order n of G and the cofactor are:
>   n = 01 00000000 00000000 00000000 0001DCE8 D2EC6184 CAF0A971
>   769FB1F7
>   h = 01

See https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/30cd4ff294252c4b6a4b69cbef6a5b4117705d22#diff-a51596fb2f3b3650972f0f650cdcf115 -- although this was initially implemented wrongly, using the field size ('degree'), and subsequently fixed to use group order (not directly in `ec_asn1.c` but by calling to `EC_KEY_priv2{buf,oct}` in `ec_key.c`) AFAICS only in 1.1.0 up.

Comment: That site gives a 502 error for me, but I edited this to add formatting. Is this how it appeared?

Comment: Thanks to @dave_thompson_085 - not least because, if you hadn't posted this, I'd probably be filing an OpenSSL bug report right now! Also, there's an X9.62 working draft dated September 1998 at "http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.202.2977&amp;rep=rep1&amp;type=pdf"

Comment: @forest: close. They used the F with two vertical strokes and serifs that means 'finite field', a combination of serif and 'typewriter' fonts, and indentation, but I think in context here those aren't needed for meaning. I was (and am) actually working from a copy I downloaded years ago, and slapped in the URL without rechecking -- my bad; I also get 502 now, but https _does_ get a valid certificate (issued Jan 10) which for several years at least it didn't. I'll try to figure out if there's any way to notify them and get this fixed.

Comment: Yeah that's what I guessed (you can do that in MathJax with `\mathbb(F)`, but sadly this site lacks MathJax support), but since there's no unicode character for that, I just made it bold instead.